# Name this TV show with a fat policeman with beret

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I'm seeking to identify a TV show I vaguely remember from my childhood. It might be 10 years old or older, I have no idea now. I don't know the country of production because I watched it dubbed to my own language.

I remember few distinct elements (1 and 7 I'm not 100% sure about but the rest I am):

1. It took place on something like a rocky island or in general rocky terrain, but I'm almost sure it was some sort of island or peninsula because I remember bodies of water, maybe a sea. If I'm not mixing up show and it was an island, there was also some tunnel to mainland that the teens of the show used to sneak out to mainland.
2. The show involved teens and the most distinctive person I remember - a slightly overweight policeman in a blue beret (it was his very distinctive feature, a blue beret and a darker blue jacket). I don't remember if there were other adults.
3. The policeman was involved in various antics with these teens and generally hating them for it. He also was portrayed as taking his job seriously but not too good at it. A general comedy relief character that the rest of the cast can make fun of.
4. I remember in one episode the policeman became friends with the teens when they told him that a fake skeleton like ones used in a biology class is his father's lost corpse. It ended with someone telling him that it's fake and showing him the holes it has in it for assembly to convince him.
5. In another episode I remember the teens playing a game at night on school computer and creating a character that looks like the policeman, and all bad things that happened in the game repeated in real life like a curse on him. One thing they did to him this way was setting his pants on fire. At the end of the episode they were sorry and tried to make the curse stop and bring the game character to safety. I also think it was something like a story game, where they had 3 choices what to do each stage and the last choice was how to go home and they picked 'ice skaters' and another option in that stage was 'taxi' that they deemed too obvious to work safely. I think they were afraid for his life at that point.
6. Another small scene from another episode I remember was that they found a homeless person who had some elixir that 'makes it easy to breathe so it prolongs life' and the policeman found his flask and was instantly hyperventilating when he took some.
7. I'm almost sure entire cast was white or close to white because I live in a purely white country and I think I'd remember as a child if I've seen on TV a lot of people that had a very different skin color that people in my country. But I might be wrong about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called ["Ship to Shore"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_to_Shore_%28TV_series%29), I hope it's the one you're looking for.

> The show centers around the lives of a group of children living on Circe Island, a fictional island off the coast of Perth, in Western Australia. Three series of the show were shot, one each in 1992, 1993 and 1996. Each episode was 24 minutes long.
>
> **The first series features comedy episodes of the children outwitting adults, particularly [security chief] Hermes Endakis, played by Greg Carroll.** The lead roles among the children were played by Clinton Voss, Jodi Herbert, Cleonie Morgon-Wootton and Heath Miller. Later series continued the comic tradition of the first series but included stories with social and environmental issues, particularly in the second series where the children try to stop a big corporation from destroying their island.

[image]

Comment: Embellished it a bit (Good call, BTW, I think that's the one).

Comment: Yes, that's it. I have marked your answer as accepted. May I ask which piece of information was the most helpful or was it the amount of details I remember that helped the most?